# "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?" Possible self intersection?

Tags: geojson, mongodb

My '2dsphere' index creation fails at a document. The command i write for creation of index is:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({'geometry' : "2dsphere"})
```

It returns the following error:

```
{
    "err" : "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:...",
    "code" : 16755,
    "n" : 0,
    "singleShard" : "localhost:27026",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The document at which the index creation fails is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53978003e6919576808d12ad"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "NumPoints" : 185
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    -123.751691277, 
                    39.26661433100003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.75229746, 
                    39.26815238500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.751289221, 
                    39.26838356800005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.751592313, 
                    39.26915259600003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.752600561, 
                    39.26892141100007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.75229746, 
                    39.26815238500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.753305692, 
                    39.26792119500004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.753002587, 
                    39.26715217100008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.756027215, 
                    39.26645855800007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.755724088, 
                    39.26568954100003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.757740455, 
                    39.26522709700004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7580436009999, 
                    39.26599610900007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.760059962, 
                    39.26553362800007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.760363134, 
                    39.26630263500005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.761371315, 
                    39.26607137900004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.761674503, 
                    39.26684038300004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.762682687, 
                    39.26660911700003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.762985891, 
                    39.26737811700008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7639940779999, 
                    39.26714684000007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.764297299, 
                    39.26791583800008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.765305489, 
                    39.26768455000007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.765608726, 
                    39.26845354500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.76661692, 
                    39.26822224700004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.766920173, 
                    39.26899123800007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.76792837, 
                    39.26875992900006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.768231639, 
                    39.26952891700006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7712562199999, 
                    39.26883493500003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.771559525, 
                    39.26960391500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.772567715, 
                    39.26937256900004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.772871036, 
                    39.27014154600005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.77387923, 
                    39.26991018900003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.774182567, 
                    39.27067916300007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.776198955, 
                    39.27021641900006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.776502318, 
                    39.27098538800004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7785187, 
                    39.27052260700003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.778822089, 
                    39.27129157000007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.781846642, 
                    39.27059733000004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.782150067, 
                    39.27136628400007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.784166423, 
                    39.27090341200005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.784469873, 
                    39.27167236100007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.785478051, 
                    39.27144091000008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.785781518, 
                    39.27220985600008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7867896989999, 
                    39.27197839500008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.787093182, 
                    39.27274733800005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.788101367, 
                    39.27251586500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.788404866, 
                    39.27328480500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7904212349999, 
                    39.27282183100004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.79072476, 
                    39.27359076600004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.791732945, 
                    39.27335926400008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.792036486, 
                    39.27412819500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.793044674, 
                    39.27389668300003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.793348231, 
                    39.27466561100005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.794356423, 
                    39.27443408800008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.794659996, 
                    39.27520301300007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.795668191, 
                    39.27497147900004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.79597178, 
                    39.27574040100006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.796979978, 
                    39.27550885700003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.797283584, 
                    39.27627777600003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.796275376, 
                    39.27650932200004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.796578979, 
                    39.27727824300007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.795570755, 
                    39.27750978400007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.795874354, 
                    39.27827870600004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7948661139999, 
                    39.27851024200004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.79516971, 
                    39.27927916600004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.794161454, 
                    39.27951069600005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.794465046, 
                    39.28027962200008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.793456774, 
                    39.28051114600004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.793760363, 
                    39.28128007500004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.79174378, 
                    39.28174310300005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.792047356, 
                    39.28251203600007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.790030727, 
                    39.28297503700003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.79033429, 
                    39.28374397400006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.777225449, 
                    39.28675272000004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7769220119999, 
                    39.28598375100006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.759778205, 
                    39.28991614500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.759171682, 
                    39.28837811900007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.758163184, 
                    39.28860935800003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.757859942, 
                    39.28784034100005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.755842946, 
                    39.28830279000005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.756146169, 
                    39.28907181100004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.755137652, 
                    39.28930302600003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.754834439, 
                    39.28853400200006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7538259249999, 
                    39.28876520600005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.753522728, 
                    39.28799617900006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.750497178, 
                    39.28868973400006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.749890862, 
                    39.28715166400008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.748882351, 
                    39.28738282800003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.747972955, 
                    39.28507571000006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7469644669999, 
                    39.28530685800007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.746055158, 
                    39.28299972700006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.745046693, 
                    39.28323086000006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.744743613, 
                    39.28246181300005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7427266829999, 
                    39.28292404800004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.742423629, 
                    39.28215499600003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.741415164, 
                    39.28238609900006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.741112126, 
                    39.28161704300004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.739095197, 
                    39.28207922000007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.738792184, 
                    39.28131015800005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.73778372, 
                    39.28154123200005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.737177733, 
                    39.28000310200008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.735160824, 
                    39.28046521500005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.73485786, 
                    39.27969614400007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.733849406, 
                    39.27992718600007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.733546458, 
                    39.27915811200006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.732538007, 
                    39.27938914300006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.732235075, 
                    39.27862006600003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.730218173, 
                    39.27908209900005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.729915267, 
                    39.27831301700007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.727898359, 
                    39.27877501200004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7275954789999, 
                    39.27800592400007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.726587024, 
                    39.27823690700006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.726284161, 
                    39.27746781600007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.718216374, 
                    39.27931536500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.717913595, 
                    39.27854625300006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.716905103, 
                    39.27877715800003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.716602339, 
                    39.27800804300006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.71559385, 
                    39.27823893700003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.715291103, 
                    39.27746981900003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.714282617, 
                    39.27770070200006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.713979886, 
                    39.27693158100004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.711962915, 
                    39.27739331900006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.711357511, 
                    39.27585506500003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.710349035, 
                    39.27608591600006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7100463529999, 
                    39.27531678600008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.70903788, 
                    39.27554762700004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7087352139999, 
                    39.27477849400003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.706718269, 
                    39.27524014500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.706415628, 
                    39.27447100700005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.703390192, 
                    39.27516341600006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.703087587, 
                    39.27439426900003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7020791049999, 
                    39.27462505300008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.701776516, 
                    39.27385590300003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.700768038, 
                    39.27408667700007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.700465465, 
                    39.27331752400005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.69945699, 
                    39.27354828700004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.699154434, 
                    39.27277913100005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.695120507, 
                    39.27370209100008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.694817997, 
                    39.27293292500008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.693809509, 
                    39.27316364200004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.693507014, 
                    39.27239447200003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.6965324289999, 
                    39.27170230300004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.696229911, 
                    39.27093314000007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.698246803, 
                    39.27047165900007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.697944273, 
                    39.26970250000005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.698952699, 
                    39.26947175000004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.69925524, 
                    39.27024090600003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.70228051, 
                    39.26954859800003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7019779409999, 
                    39.26877944900008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.702986342, 
                    39.26854866600007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.703288921, 
                    39.26931781200005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.707322499, 
                    39.26839458800004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.707625124, 
                    39.26916372400007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.710650269, 
                    39.26847121200007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.709742327, 
                    39.26616382700007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.710750667, 
                    39.26593298100005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.710145384, 
                    39.26439472600004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.719219978, 
                    39.26231679100005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.719522704, 
                    39.26308589700005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.72053097, 
                    39.26285497200007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.719925506, 
                    39.26131676600005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.720933746, 
                    39.26108583800004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.720631013, 
                    39.26031673600005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.72668026, 
                    39.25893101200006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7269830499999, 
                    39.25970009900004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.730007616, 
                    39.25900711900005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.730310442, 
                    39.25977619800005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7313186279999, 
                    39.25954518600003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.73162147, 
                    39.26031426100008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7326296589999, 
                    39.26008323900004
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.733235382, 
                    39.26162138300003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.734243584, 
                    39.26139034700003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.734546465, 
                    39.26215941600003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.740595599, 
                    39.26077301600003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.740898545, 
                    39.26154206900003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.741906721, 
                    39.26131097100006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7422096829999, 
                    39.26208002100003
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.743217863, 
                    39.26184891300005
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.743520841, 
                    39.26261796000006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.744529024, 
                    39.26238684100008
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.744832018, 
                    39.26315588500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.749872884, 
                    39.26200015500007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.751085121, 
                    39.26507627500007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.752093313, 
                    39.26484509500006
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.7526994899999, 
                    39.26638314600007
                ], 
                [ 
                    -123.751691277, 
                    39.26661433100003
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I projected this polygon on a map and I see that two points of this polygon overlap. They do not essentially intersect though but they do overlap. Is there any way to make this polygon work in MongoDB? I can surely modify the polygon to remove the overlapping point, but does anyone has a different idea?